# Homotopy group of pairs: equivalent descriptions

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

I'm reading May's *A concise Course in Algebraic Topology* and I have a question about the definition of the homotopy group of a pair. Given a pair $(X,A)$ of pointed topological spaces, the relative homotopy group is defined as $\pi_n(X,A,\ast):=\pi_{n-1}(P(X,A))$, where $P(X,A)$ is the path space associated to the inclusion $A\hookrightarrow X$, that is, the space of all paths starting at the base point of $X$ and ending at a point in $A$.

A few lines below, the author claims that we can write $\pi_n(X,A,\ast)=\left[(I^n,\partial I^n,J^n),(X,A,\ast) \right]$, where $J^n=I^{n-1}\times\{0\}\cup\partial I^{n-1}\times I$. I don't understand why we can do this.

Comment: Probably use the usual adjunction to transform a map $I^{n-1} \to P(X,A)$ into a map $I^n \to X$ and check that all conditions correspond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only makes sense if $*\in A$.  Then take the basepoint of $P(X,A)$ to be the constant path mapping $I\mapsto \{*\}$.  Now an element of $\pi_{n-1}(P(X,A))$ is a map (up to homotopy) $I^{n-1}\to P(X,A)$, sending $\partial I^{n-1}$ to the constant map.

Equivalently, it is a map (up to homotopy), $I^{n-1}\times I \to X$, which:

1. Maps $I^{n-1} \times \{0\}$ to $*$, as every path starts at $*$.
2. Maps $\partial I^{n-1}\times I$ to $*$, as the basepoint of $P(X,A)$ is the constant map to $*$.
3. Maps $I^{n-1} \times \{1\}$ to $A$, as paths end in $A$.